# How to include row values in SSRS matrix report that are not included in dataset

Tags: reporting-services

In my SSRS MATRIX report, I have 2 columns, Appraisal Company and Date with counts in that date column.  In my dataset for the dates extracted I sometimes do NOT have all the Appraisal Company included.  I have 5 Appraisal companies.  The user wants a row included for the appraisal company that was not part of the data.  Here is what my dataset returns:

[image]

This is what I'd like it to look like:

[image]

You'll notice a NEW ROW with IA in the AppraisalCompany column and a value of 0 in the Date column.  Can I accomplish this in my SSRS matrix using an expression?

Here is my SQL code if anyone make a suggestion here as well:

```
DECLARE @ActivityBeginDate date = '2019-01-01';
DECLARE @ActivityEndDate date = '2019-01-22';

SELECT 
    CASE        
        WHEN MONTH(ca.SysDate) = 1 THEN 'Jan-'+RIGHT(YEAR(ca.SysDate),2)  
        WHEN MONTH(ca.SysDate) = 2 THEN 'Feb-'+RIGHT(YEAR(ca.SysDate),2) 
        WHEN MONTH(ca.SysDate) = 3 THEN 'Mar-'+RIGHT(YEAR(ca.SysDate),2) 
        WHEN MONTH(ca.SysDate) = 4 THEN 'Apr-'+RIGHT(YEAR(ca.SysDate),2) 
        WHEN MONTH(ca.SysDate) = 5 THEN 'May-'+RIGHT(YEAR(ca.SysDate),2) 
        WHEN MONTH(ca.SysDate) = 6 THEN 'Jun-'+RIGHT(YEAR(ca.SysDate),2) 
        WHEN MONTH(ca.SysDate) = 7 THEN 'Jul-'+RIGHT(YEAR(ca.SysDate),2) 
        WHEN MONTH(ca.SysDate) = 8 THEN 'Aug-'+RIGHT(YEAR(ca.SysDate),2) 
        WHEN MONTH(ca.SysDate) = 9 THEN 'Sep-'+RIGHT(YEAR(ca.SysDate),2) 
        WHEN MONTH(ca.SysDate) = 10 THEN 'Oct-'+RIGHT(YEAR(ca.SysDate),2) 
        WHEN MONTH(ca.SysDate) = 11 THEN 'Nov-'+RIGHT(YEAR(ca.SysDate),2) 
        WHEN MONTH(ca.SysDate) = 12 THEN 'Dec-'+RIGHT(YEAR(ca.SysDate),2) 
    END as SubmittedDate,
    --cac.AppraisalCompanyID,
    cac.AppraisalCompany
FROM dbo.CMS_AppraisalCompany cac
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CMS_Appraisals ca
ON cac.AppraisalCompanyID = ca.AppraisalCompanyID
AND CAST(ca.SysDate as date) BETWEEN @ActivityBeginDate AND @ActivityEndDate
WHERE cac.AppraisalCompanyID IN (3, 9, 11, 12, 13) 
AND ca.AppraisalStatusID = 115
GROUP BY ca.SysDate, cac.AppraisalCompany, cac.AppraisalCompanyID
ORDER BY cac.AppraisalCompany asc;
```

Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated.  I tried to make this work with case statements in my stored procedure but to no avail and I was hoping that SSRS could help me accomplish this.  Hope this makes sense Thanks.

Comment: you would want to make the companies the starting point in the query and join on the dates so you keep all 5 of the company names no matter if there is or isn't data to left join on.

Comment: Thanks, Arahman, I am adding the SQL code above if you don't mind taking a look. Your time and help are appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Arahman, I finally got the issue resolved due to your input.  Again, appreciate your help.

Comment: You are welcome. I have added the solution as an answer so it can be marked as accepted and answered question. @Melinda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my earlier comment:

You would want to make the companies the starting point in the query and join on the dates so you keep all 5 of the company names no matter if there is or isn't data to left join on.

Example below

```
SELECT ...
FROM CompaniesData
LEFT JOIN DatesStuff...
LEFT JOIN DataValuesStuff...
```